# UITouch with SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

So I have an SKSpriteNode that I am spawning a bunch of from the top of the screen. The effect I am trying to achieve is that when the user taps one of the spawned nodes, only that node disappears from the view.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've sub-classed SKScene then you could write something like this:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    for(UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKNode* node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
        [node removeFromParent];
    }
}
```

Obviously this is incredibly naive, but it should get you started.

touchesBegan is the call-back when a touch is started - it receives a collection of touches.
For each touch, calculate its location within the current scene, find the node at that position, and remove the node from the scene. ARC should look after recycling the memory that node utilised (assuming you have no other pointers to it).